# How to color half of the button title

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have `UIButton` and I would like to color red only half of the title.Here is my button

```
NSString *title = AMLocalizedString(@"Remove", nil);
NSString *title1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:title, name ];
UIButton *rem = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
rem.frame = CGRectMake(140, 70, 175, 40);
[rem setTitle:title1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Remove is `"Remove" = "Delete object %@";`

I would like to color red only `name`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `NSAttributeString` in `UIButton's` `UILabel` for `iOS 6.0`.

```
yourbtn.titleLabel.attributedText = yourAttributeStringText;
```

Refer [NSAttributedStringInPractice](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSAttributedStringInPractice) link for how to use `NSAttributeString`.

When using `iOS 5.1` or `lesser version` possibilty is to use:

use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) in `UIButton's titleLabel`

Comment: I have to make my app compatible with ios 5.1. Any way to do it under iOS 6.0 ?